# C'est pour toi / c'est à toi... which one is correct?

Tags: prépositions, articles

Regarding *c'est pour toi* and *c'est à toi*: I've heard people saying both, and I want to know which one to use.

It also seems to me like *pour* and *à* can conflict. Can anyone clear out when exactly we need to use *pour* and *à*, other than the fact, we can use *à* for places?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- “*C'est pour toi* ” means “it's **for** you.”
- “*C'est à toi* ” means¹ “it's **yours**”, or¹ sometimes “it's your turn” (to play, or to do anything else).

[**This thread**](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=886172) is of interest, and seems to suggest you're trying to translate the english “to”, and has many links expanding on “basically it's a huge question”. That gives:

> [*À* is a very important French preposition](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/preposition_a.htm). Its many different meanings and uses in French include all of the following:

- Location or destination
- Distance
- Manner, style, or characteristic
- Possession
- Purpose or use
- etc.

> [The French preposition *pour*](http://french.about.com/od/grammar/a/preposition_pour.htm) usually means “for,” but has a few other possible meanings as well. It can be followed by a noun, pronoun, or infinitive, and can be used to indicate all of the following:

- Purpose / Intention
- In favor of
- Point of view
- In place of / In exchange for
- etc.

<sub>1 : Arguably, that's still the *turn* that's *yours*, so whe're still talking about possession, but oh, well.</sub>

Comment: Depending on context - which is lacking in the question - *c'est à toi* can mean "it's your turn (to play)".

Comment: I agree with Laure; I was about to answer that the sentence *C'est à toi de repondre* for example means "It's *up to you* / *your turn* to answer".

Comment: @Paola Laure: I hope this is clearer now.